# Overflow: hidden does not work with display: inline-block in Opera 12 (Presto)

Tags: css, css-float, overflow, opera, opera-presto

See this demo:
http://codepen.io/vobpler/pen/GHDCs

It's pretty simple, a button with two elements inside. There's a `.text` element which holds the text shown in the default state, then there's a `.spinner` element which holds the content that slides down when you click the button.

```
<button class="button load-btn">
  <span class="text">Press me!</span>
  <span class="spinner"><i class="icon">:D</i></span>
</button>
```

It works fine in Chrome, and pretty good in Firefox as well, but in Opera Presto (the old version 12 to be specific) both child elements (`.text` and `.spinner`) sticks out of the container. I do have `overflow: hidden;` applied, so it *should* be cut off (like it does in Chrome/FF).

After playing around with it a bit i noticed that it works if i change the `display` property to `block` or apply a float. That'll work, but i would prefer to keep it as `inline-block` if possible. Are there any other workarounds for this bug?

Screenshots in Opera:

```
http://i.imgur.com/MtwZQMU.png // Before click
http://i.imgur.com/RfODQ64.png // After click
```